# Find out parents of an element in XML files

Tags: xml

I have a **large** (10k lines) XML file.
Normally i use **Notepad++** or **Chrome** to open XML files.
Although it is possible to collapse/uncollapse child entries, i can't see which element has which parents.

For example:

```
<parent1>
<parent2>
<parent3>
<element1>
my aim entry
</element1>
</parent3>
</parent2>
</parent1>
```

Every time i want to check parents of **element1** i check upper lines, collapse/uncollapse them to find out that actual heritage is like this:

```
parent1.parent2.parent3.element1
```

Is it possible to find this heritage by a program?
Because i do this job for this big XML file every week and sometimes I make errors and all system breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good XML editors will have this future, one that's used by IBM for instance is [oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have `xmllint` (should be on Linux/OS X by default, otherwise [here](http://xmlsoft.org/downloads.html)), just do:

```
xmllint --shell your-xml-file.xml
```

Then formulate the following XPath query:

```
xpath //element1/ancestor::*
```

The result would be:

```
Object is a Node Set :
Set contains 3 nodes:
1  ELEMENT parent1
2  ELEMENT parent2
3  ELEMENT parent3
```